# My iPhones UIkit on adobe xd has its icons replaced with a question mark?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience, adobe-xd

I'm working on my own `wireframe` on `adobe xd` software and have downloaded the `UIkit` for the `iPhone X`. However, I've noticed that certain icons such as the back arrow button or other things like the icon of the bottom navigation bar have all been replaced by a question mark icon.

I was told that when I downloaded the `UIkit`, the icons should have been there instead of the questions mark icons. If you know of any method to solve this issue, do let me know.

Comment: You need to install the updated Apple fonts.  Specifically, SF Pro -> https://developer.apple.com/fonts/